# How to properly store UTC datetime and work with local offset?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, timezone, utc

I am storing data as UTC, but I am very confused on how to properly retrieve it. I store the value as UTC in a datetime column in MSSQL. Currently the way I retrieve it is by setting the GMT offset to the start datetime range and end datetime range. I am also needing to apply aggregation to that datetime field (group by) and display it in the user's proper local timezone.  The issue I am having is say if I look for a range today it will pull up columns that match correctly, but the datetime value in those columns can be different UTC days; I am grouping by day. So for example when someone selects a range for the beginning of the day and the end (for today) they are presented with UTC datetime values from yesterday and today; but if I try to apply the GMT offset to the display value it still comes out as possibly 2 different dates. How can I properly coordinate the range and the display?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Converting UTC format date to Standard time of CST or EST (for example) is straight forward. We have to store the offset value in a separate column or table for each timezone which we need in our application.

For example: UTC to CST is -6 hrs. Similarly UTC to EST is -5 hrs.

```
DECLARE @UTC_Date DATETIME
SET @UTC_Date = GETUTCDATE()

SELECT
 @UTC_Date AS [UTC],
 DATEADD(hh, -6, @UTC_Date) AS [CST - Standard Time],
 DATEADD(hh, -5, @UTC_Date) AS [EST - Standard Time]
```

It gets complicated once we bring in Daylight saving into calculation. But if the given date falls under daylight saving then the above calculation won't work.

**So how is Daylight saving calculated?**

1. If the year <= 2006 then daylight saving is between:
   2 am on First Sunday in April till 2 am on Last Sunday in October
2. If the year >= 2007 then daylight saving is between:
   2 am on Second Sunday in March till 2 am on First Sunday in November
3. UTC to CST (Standard Time) = -6
4. UTC to CDT (Daylight Time) = -5
5. UTC to EST (Standard Time) = -5
6. UTC to EDT (DayLight Time) = -4

Check out the solution for handling daylight saving here - http://vadivel.blogspot.com/2011/10/timezone-conversion-utc-to-cst-with.html